# C# how to determine which object to deserialize to

Tags: c#

I'm calling a Web API that is returning a JSON payload.  One of the fields is sometimes a boolean and sometimes it's a JSON object itself.

Is there a way to determine if I have a class I'm deserializing  (document) or the field that is sometimes just a Boolean?  When I get the Boolean it throws an error.

I supposed I could try one class and if there is an error try another but seems like there should be a better way to do this.  Example JSON would be

```
{
  "field1":"value1",
  "field2":false
}
```

VS

```
{
  "field1":"value1",
  "field2":
  {
    "field21":"value21",
    "field22":"value22"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that given the fact that API you interact with has bad design your solution is quite acceptable

Comment: Whoever wrote that web service should have his computer taken from him.  A service should always return a consistent object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest2
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var json1 = "{\"field1\":\"value1\",\"field2\":true}";
        var deserializedWithBool = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectJson>(json1);

        var json2 = "{\"field1\":\"value1\",\"field2\": { \"field21\" : \"value21\", \"field22\" : \"value22\"}}";
        var deserializedWithObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectJson>(json2);

        Assert.AreEqual(true, deserializedWithBool.field2.field2BoolResult);
        Assert.AreEqual("value21", deserializedWithObject.field2.field21);
    }
}

public class ObjectJson
{
    public string field1 { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(FieldJsonConverter))]
    public FieldResult field2 { get; set; }
}

public class FieldResult
{
    public bool? field2BoolResult { get; set; }
    public string field21 { get; set; }
    public string field22 { get; set; }
}

public class FieldJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(FieldResult));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Boolean)
        {
            return new FieldResult() { field2BoolResult  = (bool)(JValue)token };
        }
        else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            return token.ToObject<FieldResult>();
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

Use json.net then create Custom jsonConverter example above:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: What about the `false` value when `field2` is a bool?

Comment: You added lot of complexity by introducing converter but didn't solve the actual problem.

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying to figure out form the example provided, I like that @ranton187 provided an example but I'm missing how when field2 is a bool what happens then.

Comment: @ChrisWard if you are going to stick with this approach you'll have to make the result class more generic (which would contain both complex and boolean fields) and add more complex logic into `ReadJson` to decide which field to populate with data. Personally I don't see any reason to over-complicate the solution with this approach in compare with fallback way you currently use.

Comment: updated my answer.. all comments and answers are correct it is your choice whatever path you choose.. @ChrisWard

Comment: @ranton187 Thank you for clearing up your example I follow what your doing now and I agree for this it might be easier to just try both classes using an exception handler then to add all this additional code.  This API is s2member which is a membership plugin for Wordpress.  Not my choice just what I'm trying to integrate with to confirm a user is actually a paid member of a club.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a generic type to store Field2...

```cs
    public class MyClassBase<T>
    {
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public T Field2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Field
    {
        public string Field21 { get; set; }
        public string Field22 { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestJsonDeserialise
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            var json1 = @"{
          'field1':'value1',
          'field2':
          {
          'field21':'value21',
          'field22':'value22'
          }
        }";

            var json2 = @"{
          'field1':'value1',
          'field2':false 
        }";

            var json = json2;
            var field2 = JObject.Parse(json)["field2"];

            object myClass = null;
            switch (field2.Type)
            {
                case JTokenType.Object:
                    myClass = GetMyClass<MyClassBase<Field>>(json);
                    break;
                case JTokenType.Boolean:
                    myClass = GetMyClass<MyClassBase<bool>>(json);
                    break;
            }

            switch (myClass)
            {
                case MyClassBase<Field> fieldResult:
                    //When FieldResult then do stuff
                    Console.WriteLine("You got an Object");
                    break;
                case MyClassBase<bool> boolResult:
                    //You got a bool back
                    Console.WriteLine("You got a bool");
                    break;
            }
        }

        public T GetMyClass<T>(string json)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make your own implementation of the [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) class and use the attribute `[JsonConverter(typeof(YourJsonConverter))]`

You can then apply your own implementation for deserialization of the property.

You can override the `ReadJson` method to examine the type of object, and act accordingly.

Comment: I understand that author hasn't specified the criteria behind the "better" term but it's definitely unclear why and from what perspective this approach is better.